# Error: Invalid arguments: authority not provided for transaction signed by keypair

Tags: wallet, keypair, error

I have a code that uses keypair from file to sign transactions.

```
  const payer = Keypair.fromSecretKey(BufferJs.from(keypair));
  const wallet = new anchor.Wallet(payer);

  ////
  ////

  const tx = await rewardPoolProgram.rpc.initializePool(
    nonce,
    rewardDuration,
    lockPeriod,
    {
      accounts: {
        authority: wallet.publicKey,
        stakingMint: tokenMint.publicKey,
        stakingVault,
        rewardMint: tokenMint.publicKey,
        rewardVault,
        poolSigner: poolSigner,
        pool: pool.publicKey,
        tokenProgram: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
      },
      signers: [pool],
      instructions: [
        await rewardPoolProgram.account.pool.createInstruction(pool),
      ],
    }
  );
```

It used to work fine months ago, today I tried it again and have this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invalid arguments: authority not provided.
    at common.ts:50:1
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at validateAccounts (common.ts:45:1)
    at ix (instruction.ts:28:1)
    at txFn (transaction.ts:17:1)
    at Object.rpc [as initializePool] (rpc.ts:16:1)
    at createPool (createPool.ts:34:1)
    at async onFinish (CreatePool.tsx:22:1)
```

Does Solana no longer allow to sign transaction by keypair anymore?

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: @JacobCreech Added code to the question

Comment: Without the source code of `rewardPoolProgram` this will be difficult for most to answer. I'm voting to close this question unless we can get a more complete picture of the problem.